# Left join and count in same query return incorrect result

Tags: php, mysql, join

The problem is that if there is 0 comment or 1 comment the count shows 1 while the rest is working well means that 2, 3, etc working fine.

```
$sql  = "SELECT blog.*,count(blog.id) as Total FROM blog  left JOIN comment on   comment.id = blog.id GROUP BY date desc";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT b.date, count(c.id) as Total
FROM blog b LEFT JOIN
     comment c 
     ON c.id = b.id
GROUP BY b.date DESC;
```

This assumes that `date` comes from `blog` (which should be the case if your current query is working).  The difference is that you are counting from the *second* table, not the *first*.

This does not use `*` for columns from `blog`.  That is usually a very, very bad idea when using `GROUP BY`.  The best practice (enforced by almost all SQL engines) is to only include unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` when they are in the `GROUP BY`.

Note:  It seems very awkward that the same column `id` is used for the `JOIN` between two very different entities (blogs and comments).

Answer (score 0):

i just change to count(comment.id) from count(blog.id)